# remove rows not begin with certain string

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this: first column is partially match with the second column

```
dats<-data.frame(ID=c(1:3),row1=c("do","cat","me"),
                 row2=c("dog","dogcat","exomec"))
```

I want to only keep the rows that match **starts from beginning** (i.e. only the first row) and remove those match starts in the middle or at the end.

my goal dataset is

```
  ID row1   row2
1  1   do    dog
```

**Thank you!!!**

Answer (score 1):

We can use `filter` with `str_detect` which is vectorized over string and pattern.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dats %>% filter(str_detect(row2, paste0('^', row1)))

#  ID row1 row2
#1  1   do  dog
```

Comment: Thank you for such quick answer! I spent over an hour to try&fail...